# Simple JS array `concat` clarification

Tags: javascript, arrays, this

I understand how the `concat` method works, but I had one question about a line in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat#Description).

It says:

> The `concat` methods does not alter `this` or any of the arrays provided as arguments but instead returns a shallow copy that contains copies of the same elements combined from the original arrays.

---

My questions is, how is it possible for it to *potentially* alter the `this`? Is it saying that the argument arrays could potentially lose their `this` but instead it preserves it since it's simply creating a new array?

Comment: When `const arr4 = arr1.concat(arr2, arr3);` is called, `arr1` is the `this` value within `concat`. I think, the quote says that neither `arr1`, `arr2` nor `arr3` are altered, aka mutated. This means `arr4` doesn’t have the same reference as any of the three other arrays, so it’s a completely new array. If `concat` altered the `this` value, then `arr1` would be mutated, which doesn’t happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the call `a.concat(b, c)`, the function being called is `a.concat`, the *this* value is `a`, and the arguments are `b` and `c`. What MDN is saying there is that the array `a` is not changed by that call – unlike, for example, `a.push(x)`.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

arr.concat([4, 5]);
console.log(arr.join(', '));
// the “this” array in the call `arr.concat([4, 5])` didn’t change

arr.push(6);
console.log(arr.join(', '));
// the “this” array in the call `arr.push(6)` changed
```

Answer (score 3):

Some functions *mutate* the arguments that are passed into it, or mutate their calling context. One example is `.sort()` - if you take an array `someArr` and then do `const result = someArr.sort()`, both the `result` *and the* original `someArr` will be sorted (they will reference the same object).

In contrast, `concat` does not mutate any of the passed arrays, nor its calling context. One without prior knowledge of JS might think that `concat` adds items to the array `concat` is being called on, like the following code does:

```js
Array.prototype.myConcat = function(...arrs) {
  arrs.forEach((arr) => {
    arr.forEach(item => {
      this.push(item);
    });
  });
}

const orig = [1, 2, 3];
const another = [4, 5, 6];
orig.myConcat(another);

console.log(orig);
```

But this is not how the native `concat` function works - it creates an *entirely new* array instead, which is what the documentation there is intending to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

When a function is called as a method of an object (such as an array in this example), `this` is set to the object the method is called on. I think this is the most important thing to take away from this ...

In other words the documentation is simply saying that the original object on which `concat` is being invoked would not be mutated since it `concat` creates a **brand new array**. So `concat` is one of the few array functions which do not mutate the `this`. `Array.sort`/`Array.push` as mentioned already do mutate the context on which they are called on.

Functions which do not mutate the context they are called on or their arguments in some cases are preferred since they do not cause any side-effects. They are also called `pure` functions since with a given input they always produce the same output while producing zero side-effects.

There is an entire sub-set of lodash for example called [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) dedicated on the idea of pure functions and functional programming due to some of those advantages. There is also [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) etc.

Hope this helps.